# Send JSON data from Android to PHP script

Tags: android, json, http-post

I am using this code to send data with JSON object, but my code says that I sending null `'jsonResponse is always null'`. I can't see where my problem is, I am not sure with this line of code 
`String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());` EntityUtils class is deprecated in android.

```
public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

    String url = "http://192.168.52.170/socketIO/examples/chat/public/";

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
        JSONObject json = data[0];
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);

        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json="+json.toString());
            post.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            post.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse response;
            response = client.execute(post);
            String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(resFromServer);
            Log.i("Response from server", jsonResponse.getString("msg"));
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

        return jsonResponse;
    }

}
```

Comment: you will get json response in postExecute() of AyncTask, Override poseExecute()

Comment: Use this code it should help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56476266/4776577

Comment: check your response status also check the respone string first if it null or not.

Comment: Please find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114698/send-a-json-object-from-android-to-php-server-with-post-method-and-httpurlconnec.  Thank u